# Do I need to pay the real estate agency if the contract was signed after I moved in?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, real-estate

I have signed a very standard rental agreement with a landlord. I have contacted him through a real estate agency, because they were the ones who posted the ad on the Internet. They did not participate or otherwise influence me signing the contract with the landlord.

I was also pressured into signing a contract with the real estate agency, after I moved in. I say pressured, because it was presented to me before showing me a draft, and I was manipulated into signing it after taking a casual glance - stupid, but there's no changing that now.

The contract states that I am to pay 1.5x the normal rent if the agency undertakes steps that result in me signing a rental agreement with the landlord, or if I rent the property anyway after signing this contract within two years of signing it.

Now, the agreement with the agency has been signed after the rental agreement, and after I've moved in - my understanding is that since the conditions in the contract are not satisifed, I am not obliged to pay anything - is that correct?

Comment: Who are you paying rent to, the landlord or the real estate agent?  The terms of the agreement you signed with the agent matter, and it isn't possible to answer without a better understanding of what might constitute "*undertakes steps that result in me signing a rental agreement*".  Do you have a specific quote from the contract that goes into more detail?  Because if you engaged their services but made an end-around to circumvent paying them then you didn't operate in good faith.  But if you simply became aware of a property through their ad, they may not have performed on their end.

Comment: And what you mean by "*have contacted him through a real estate agency.*" matters too. Because although there might be a good and legitimate question in here, it really sounds like you used the agency and are now trying to get out of paying them for their service on a technicality.  Because if you went straight to the landlord and signed a lease how would the agent even know?  P.S.  Jurisdiction also matters...

Comment: Are you asking whether your contract is valid?  I think that very much varies according to jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

> I have contacted him through a real estate agency

means that they did

> undertakes steps that result in me signing a rental agreement with the landlord

You signed the contract, you are bound by its terms.

Comment: The terms state that the payment is due if those steps take place after signing it.